# How to save html input variables after session timeout

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, session, timeout

In my mvc project after session timeout it redirects to main page. How to save input variables that I fill before and click on submit, but because of session timeout it redirects and all data is lost...

Comment: That's [how sessions work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178581(v=vs.100)), some persistence with a predefined limit - so if it takes too long for an end user between requests, it will timeout as it should. You can extend the session time, and/or, depending on the sensitivity of the data [persist on the client](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) also based on some time limit/expiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used local storage. Before session time out I saved data in local storage and every next request saved it again.